# Getting status from a database

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table with columns `id (PK)`, `tid (FK)`, `lid(FK)`, and `status (Varchar)`. For each `tid` there are several `lid`, for each `lid` there is a `status`: "Finish" or "ongoing".

I want to get the status of each `tid`, where a `tid`'s status is: if all `lid` for the `tid` have status "Finish" then the `tid` status is "Finish", if any `lid` status is "ongoing" then the `tid` status is "ongoing".

Here's what I have done so far:

```
st2=con.createStatement();
String QueryString2 = "SELECT status from lo_status where topic_id='"+topicid+"'";
rs2 = st2.executeQuery(QueryString2);
while (rs2.next()) {
    status=rs2.getString(1);
}

if(status == null){
    status="Pending";
}
else if(status.equals("Finished")){
    status="Finished";
}else{
    status="Ongoing";
}
```

---

Comment: Give a clear template of your table(s). If all these columns are there in a single table then it is too easy, in case of different tables let you provide some detail about tables.

Comment: these r in same table only..

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following.

```
SELECT count(rowid) total from lo_status where topic_id='"+topicid+"' and status="Finished";
```

If total = 0, the status is finished, else it is ongoing.

Comment: Above code is working fine,i just want to know the tid for which it is finished..

Comment: You just passed the tid to the query, why don't you use that. And if my solution works, please mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Following Query.

```
Select  count(status) As total  from lo_status where topic_id='"+topicid+"' and status =ongoing";
if(total>0){
 status="OnGoing";
}else
{
 status="Finished";
}
```

You can try it and If any query then asked.

Comment: you want to for which tid it is finished?

Comment: I have one idea. You can put the query in the for loop and check for all the tid. you get how many and which tid is Finished.You got my Point?